# retrieving data from an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a large array (list of dictionaries) in javascript and I have to retrieve data from the array in a specific format here is an example of a snippet of the array

```
data = [{"userId":1, "completed":true},
        {"userId":1, "completed":false},
        {"userId":1, "completed":true},
        {"userId":2, "completed":false},
        {"userId":2, "completed":true}
]
```

what I had to do was retrieve the userId and the count of (completed) if its value is true
eg ouput = {1, 2} for userId:1
i tried filtering and looping but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: What do you mean by "if its value is true eg ouput = {1, 2}"? Probably gave an example of the expected output based on the date you wrote here.

Comment: i mean if the value of the key completed is true

Comment: Again, try to create expected output, something in the form of JSON. What does `{1,2} mean`?

Comment: that is just an example of how the output  should be - the user with id = 1 has 2 completed keys with the value true

Comment: You say you tried something but you don't show what you tried. You should.

Comment: @Malcom are you trying to return a new object with the userId and the total completed? If that's the case, you can use the reduce method to solve this problem. Could you edit your post and provide more details about what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might want to use reduce and group them by userId. So maybe this:

```js
const data = [
    {"userId":1, "completed":true},
    {"userId":1, "completed":false},
    {"userId":1, "completed":true},
    {"userId":2, "completed":false},
    {"userId":2, "completed":true}
];

const usersByCompleteds = data.reduce((retval, item) => {
    if(item.completed) {
      retval[item.userId] = retval[item.userId] + 1 || 1;
    }
    return retval;
}, {});

console.log(usersByCompleteds);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method to loop through the array. For each object, it checks if `completed` value is `true`, and if so, increments the count for the corresponding `userId` in the `userCounts` object. The resulting `userCounts` object contains the counts of completed tasks for each user where `completed` is true.

```js
const data = [
  { userId: 1, completed: true },
  { userId: 1, completed: false },
  { userId: 1, completed: true },
  { userId: 2, completed: false },
  { userId: 2, completed: true }
];

const userCounts = {};

data.forEach(item => {
  if (item.completed) {
    const userId = item.userId;
    userCounts[userId] = (userCounts[userId] || 0) + 1;
  }
});

console.log(userCounts);
```

You can make it a bit shorter, basically an [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```js
const data = [
  { userId: 1, completed: true },
  { userId: 1, completed: false },
  { userId: 1, completed: true },
  { userId: 2, completed: false },
  { userId: 2, completed: true }
];

const userCounts = {};

data.forEach(({userId, completed}) => completed && (userCounts[userId] = (userCounts[userId] || 0) + 1));

console.log(userCounts);
```